# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type'(String)' in my firstViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

firstViewController. This is where the problem is. In my 'for loop' it is giving me an error. I have tried to use what Xcode suggested, but it isn't working. I still consider myself a beginner with Swift. I looked at other answers when people have posted the same question and I still can't solve my problem.

```
 import UIKit

var toDoItems:[String] = []

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tasksTable:UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return toDoItems.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        if var storedToDoItems : AnyObject?  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") {

            toDoItems = []

            for var i = 0; i < storedToDoItems?.count(); ++i {
                toDoItems.append(storedToDoItems[i] as! String)
            }

        }

        tasksTable?.reloadData()
    }


}
```

This is my secondViewController.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var toDoItem: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addItemButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        toDoItems.append(toDoItem.text)

        let fixedToDoItems = toDoItems

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(fixedToDoItems, forKey: "todDoItems")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load your to-do list array from `NSUserDefaults`, use `if let` to test if it's a `[String]` (that is, an array of strings), and then you won't need to cast it to a `String` later on, which might be contributing to your error. Try replacing your `viewWillAppear` method with this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if let storedToDoItems = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") as? [String] {

        toDoItems = []

        for var i = 0; i < storedToDoItems.count; ++i {
            toDoItems.append(storedToDoItems[i])
        }
    }

    tasksTable?.reloadData()
}
```

While you're at it, there's a much nicer way to loop over the contents of an array in Swift (and many other languages):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if let storedToDoItems = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") as? [String] {

        toDoItems = []

        for item in storedToDoItems {
            toDoItems.append(item)
        }
    }

    tasksTable?.reloadData()
}
```

In this case however, you should be able to just set your variable directly from the loaded one:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if let storedToDoItems = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoItems") as? [String] {
        toDoItems = storedToDoItems
    }

    tasksTable?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks @Robert. Now I am trying to get the array to show in the console. It isn't showing the element that i put in the array.

Comment: I guess I can use just a simple println() to print it to the console to show the elements.

Comment: You should be able to add a `println(toDoItems)` as the last thing of the `if let` block to verify it correctly loaded your items.

Comment: I did that, but It still isn't showing the items that should be loaded.

Comment: What happens instead? If it's nothing, then the `if let` statement is probably failing (it can't find an array of strings in `NSUserDefaults`). Try adding an `else` to the `if let` to see if that is indeed the case. If it is, you probably haven't written to `NSUserDefaults` "toDoItems" (or what you have written isn't an array of strings).

Comment: Yes. Since I used the `else` statement, it adds the item to the array.